# Can you poison a Bag of Devouring?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, monsters

According to the description of the [Bag of Devouring](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/cursed-items/#TOC-Bag-of-Devouring):

> This bag appears to be an ordinary sack. Detection for magical properties makes it seem as if it were a bag of holding. The sack, however, is something entirely different and more insidious—one of the feeding orifices of an extradimensional creature.

Specifically, the "feeding orifice" part implies that something eats whatever you put inside of it.

Could I place poison or something similarly damaging/lethal inside the bag in order to kill the extradimensional creature?

Comment: Does this question reduce down to "is there a stat block for the extradimensional creature so that we can determine the effect of poison on it?"  I think it does, but I am not smart enough on PF to know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## You cannot, but see Dragon #271

The *Bag of Devouring* has been listed as a magic item of dubious value since the first edition of AD&D and has been consistently described in that and subsequent versions, including Pathfinder, as the mouth of an extra dimensional creature. No edition of the rules has included a description of that creature however. Now defunct Dragon Magazine included a long-running series of "Ecology of..." articles, and the *bag* does receive treatment there according to AD&D 2nd edition rules just months before the release of 3e, on which Pathfinder was based.

Issue #271 of **Dragon Magazine**, May 2000, includes an article on p. 82 by Kevin Haw entitled "*The Ecology of the Bag of Devouring: Hiders Keepers*." While the article does specify that the extra dimensional creature is immune to poison, it provides details about the creature, including its combat statistics, which could be used for determining how to kill the creature.

Here are a few details pulled from the article which is presented as a first-person narrative with game mechanics called out as footnotes:

- The interior of the bag is 32" in diameter and 5' deep. [Although for that diameter a 5'4.46" depth is required to yield the DMG-specified 30 cubic feet.]
- The interior is AC 7 [that's AC 13 in Pathfinder terms] and will withstand 15+1d6 points of damage before ripping. If ripped the *bag* is destroyed, forming a 10-foot-wide vortex to the Astral plan, just as if a *portable hole* were placed within a *bag of holding*.
- A devourer launches an acid attack if any damage is inflicted from inside the bag...

The article goes on to include an anatomical diagram of the extra dimensional creature and additional details which I will not reproduce out of respect for copyright and in the interest of preserving some surprise for the players whose DM finds and uses this article.

Comment: Dragon magazine is specifically a dungeon and dragons magazine while i am asking for Pathfinder Bag of devouring.

Comment: It's true that this article was written for AD&D 2nd edition shortly before the release of 3e on which Pathfinder was based, so you may find a need to adjust the statistics for your purposes. The article was written for the same concept of a Bag of Devouring which has been present through most editions of the game.

Comment: This feels like the start of a good answer, but could you include some details about the issue?

Comment: The devourer is immune to all poisons and acids p84 at the bottom.

Comment: @ravery thanks very much for that catch! Don't know how I missed it.

Comment: And now I need to run this -_-